# Pushing content from one WordPress website to another on same domain

Tags: wordpress, push

I have two WordPress installations, WPStaging and WPLive which both sit on the same domain but in different directories.

I've tried using two plugins to push content from one to another which are: -

- Push Syndication
- SitePush

Push Syndication seems to work but doesn't push the pages, it only pushes posts. Where as SitePush doesn't work when the two sites are on the same domain, I haven't tried them on sub domains yet but will.

My question's are as follows: -

- Does anyone have a fixed for Push Syndication because it so nearly
  works and is very quick to set up?
- If not does anyone have a better
  solution instead of these plugins?

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to migrate it manually? 
It should be really easy. You have to follow three simple steps.

Please, look at this and let me know if you need some more help.
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/transfer-wordpress/

Comment: Link-only answers don't add much value to StackOverflow. It would be more helpful if you could explain the steps needed in your post.

Comment: I don't want to migrate, i want to use one site as a staging site so that content can be approved before going live.